# CSS border-radius problem in IE

Tags: css

I have a problem with border-radius. I have CSS like this:

```
div#askWindow, div#orderWindow{
position: fixed;
top: 17%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -128px;
width: 257px;
background-color:#fff;
padding:10px 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-khtml-border-radius: 20px;     
border-radius: 20px;
behavior: url(PIE.htc);}
```

Actually, it's css for jqModal windows, but i've tried this stuff without plugin.
In IE8 there is no effect with it. It seems the same thing with IE7.
Where am I wrong here?

Comment: Anything that starts with -moz, -webkit or -khtml will not work in IE, since those are browser-specific properties.

Comment: but i put behavior: url(PIE.htc); from http://css3pie.com/

Comment: Make sure your PIE.htc is loading.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS `border-radius` property (and all browser variations) do not work in IE8 or below. Those versions do not implement CSS3.

**EDIT #1**

Because you are using CSS3PIE, make sure the path to the rule file is correct. Where is it located relative to your stylesheet?

**EDIT #2**

The CSS3PIE site hosts their PIE.htc file in their root server directory. Try placing yours there and use `behavior: url(/PIE.htc)` in the stylesheet.

Comment: i know, that's why i'm using behavior:url(...); here

Comment: btw, with the recent firefox 5 now you can drop the -moz- for border-radius, but since there are many firefox v < 5 around, likely it is better you keep it.

Comment: @Anton - Are you sure your PIE.htc is loading?

Comment: my PIE.htc is located in css files folder

Comment: is the path of the url for behavior correct? I am just reading it behaves a bit differently from other cases, i.e. it must be relative to document root — in your case you shoould place it into / of your site, it seems

Comment: i'm doing local things without any webservers. i tried /PIE.htc and PIE.htc. By the way i don't see PIE.htc in Developer tools in Chrome.

Comment: @Anton - Then it should be http://http://localhost/css/PIE.htc (or whatever your directory path is).

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, but try using quotes around the filename.

Comment: i tried this path C:\Users\Sorino\Desktop\belkit-html2\css\PIE.htc but still have problem :(

Comment: @Anton: The CSS3PIE site hosts theirs in the root site folder. Make sure it's there and use `url(/PIE.htc)`. See my edit #2.

Comment: you tried the local path as absolute path? you should try at most http://localhost/css/PIE.htc as Jared Farrish suggested

Comment: I meant it seemed like you used `url(C:\Users\...)`; using `url(http://css3pie.com/PIE.htc)` should be ok

Comment: @Evan Mulawski about your first EDIT, the relative url in the behavior property in the case of IE(8 or less) is relative to the document root, not to the location of the css as expected and "normal". At least, it seams so in what I've read about http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/

Comment: @Anton: Place the PIE.htc file in your root site folder. Use the code in my second edit in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the given examples, you must put your .htc into the same folder of your document if you are using url(name.htc), not inside you css folder, unless it is also the same dir where your document is.

I.e. the relative URL is relative to the document root (e.g. localhost/index.html), not to the dir where the css that defines the property is (localhost/css/).

Comment: and for browser < IE8, or even for IE8 not in standard mode (!), you should use -ms- prefix